# How to track changes & update only few columns?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Can't select the whole object as the table contains more than 50 columns. I have projected only one column.

```
var qryCheckTemplteUpdate = ctx.usermasters.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(um => um.id == long.Parse(userID) && um.delflag == "0")
    .Select(um => new { um.templateupdateflag} )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is it possible to track changes for this column & update into DB.

Comment: not on the anonymous object. You have to create an entity object out of it and then attach to the context.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pull one record out, update 1 column, and save it back? EF should be smart enough to know you only changed that one column and generate an update statement that only updates the one column.

Comment: @AnthonyChu, I worried about select statement, I don't want to read all the columns, just to update one.